# In this code i want to change the variable name 'frontenditems' and 'whoAmI' wheneve i clicked check and radiobutton but it is showing olny on

Tags: vue.js, frontend

```
<template>
    <p>FrontEnd Items</p>

<label for="vue">Vue.js</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="vue" id="vue" v-model="frontendItems">

<label for="React">React.js</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="React" id="React" v-model="frontendItems">

<label for="Angular">Angular.js</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="Angular" id="Angular" v-model="frontendItems">

<p>
    You have selected :- {{ frontendItems }}
</p>

<p>For radio Buttons</p>
<p>Who am I</p>
<label for="developer">Developer</label>
<input type="radio" name="developer" id="developer" v-model="whoAmI">

<label for="programmer">Programmer</label>
<input type="radio" name="programmer" id="programmer" v-model="whoAmI">

<p>
    I am :- {{ whoAmI }}
</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name : 'CheckRadiobinding',
    data(){
        return {
            frontendItems:[],
            whoAmI : null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In frontend items i want to get stored array values 'vue', 'react' and 'angular' and in whoAmI varaiable i want to get either developer or programmer whenever i click check and radio button but I am only getting 'on' as a value

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `value` on each of your inputs. When a checkbox or radio input is selected `value` is what gets added to your v-model array

```html
<template>
  <p>FrontEnd Items</p>

  <label for="vue">Vue.js</label>
  <input
    id="vue"
    v-model="frontendItems"
    value="Vue.js"
    type="checkbox"
    name="vue"
  />

  <label for="React">React.js</label>
  <input
    id="React"
    v-model="frontendItems"
    value="React.js"
    type="checkbox"
    name="React"
  />

  <label for="Angular">Angular.js</label>
  <input
    id="Angular"
    v-model="frontendItems"
    value="Angular.js"
    type="checkbox"
    name="Angular"
  />

  <p>You have selected :- {{ frontendItems }}</p>

  <p>For radio Buttons</p>
  <p>Who am I</p>
  <label for="developer">Developer</label>
  <input
    id="developer"
    v-model="whoAmI"
    value="Developer"
    type="radio"
    name="developer"
  />

  <label for="programmer">Programmer</label>
  <input
    id="programmer"
    v-model="whoAmI"
    value="Programmer"
    type="radio"
    name="programmer"
  />

  <p>I am :- {{ whoAmI }}</p>
</template>
```